# Spring Security persistent Remember me with MongoDB does not save tokens

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-security, remember-me, spring-data-mongodb

I try to implement a service to allow mobile apps to connect and retrieve information from my server.

I included Spring Security with my CustomUserDetail but without the login form, I received data in Json and I logged the users manually with

```
    Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

Now I need to implementthe remember-me services with MongoDB but I am unable to get the tokens stored on my DB. How can I simulate the "remember-me" check when I log the users? It is mandatory because if do not do it all users are logged out each time I restart the server

this is my security config file:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices" key="myPersistentKey" />
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/users/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
    <form-login authentication-failure-url="/denied" login-page="/denied" />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/denied" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="com.service.test.security.CustomUserDetailsService" />

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="md5" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="mongoDBTokenRepository" class="com.service.test.security.MongoPersistentTokenRepositoryImpl" />

<beans:bean id="rememberMeServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="myPersistentKey" />
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="customUserDetailsService" />
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="mongoDBTokenRepository" />
    <beans:property name="alwaysRemember" value="true" />
</beans:bean>
```

The MongoPersistentTokenRepositoryImpl which is my implementation of PersistentTokenRepository

```
@Autowired
private RememberMeTokenRepository rememberMeTokenRepository;

@Override
public void createNewToken(PersistentRememberMeToken token) {
    RememberMeToken newToken = new RememberMeToken(token);
    this.rememberMeTokenRepository.save(newToken);
}

@Override
public void updateToken(String series, String tokenValue, Date lastUsed) {
    RememberMeToken token = this.rememberMeTokenRepository.findBySeries(series);
    if (token != null) {
        token.setTokenValue(tokenValue);
        token.setDate(lastUsed);
        this.rememberMeTokenRepository.save(token);
    }

}

@Override
public PersistentRememberMeToken getTokenForSeries(String seriesId) {
    RememberMeToken token = this.rememberMeTokenRepository.findBySeries(seriesId);
    return new PersistentRememberMeToken(token.getUsername(), token.getSeries(), token.getTokenValue(), token.getDate());
}

@Override
public void removeUserTokens(String username) {
    List<RememberMeToken> tokens = this.rememberMeTokenRepository.findByUsername(username);
    this.rememberMeTokenRepository.delete(tokens);
}
```

and this is my CustomUserDetailsService that implements UserDetailsService

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

/**
 * Returns a populated {@link UserDetails} object. The username is first retrieved from the database and then mapped
 * to a {@link UserDetails} object.
 */
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    try {
        User21 domainUser = userRepository.findByEmail(email);

        boolean enabled = true;
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;

        return new CustomUser(domainUser.getId(), domainUser.getEmail(), domainUser.getPassword().toLowerCase(), enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked,
        // getAuthorities(domainUser.getRole().getRole()));
                getAuthorities(2));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

/**
 * Returns a populated {@link UserDetails} object. The username is first retrieved from the database and then mapped
 * to a {@link UserDetails} object.
 */
public UserDetails loadUser(User21 user) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    try {

        boolean enabled = true;
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;

        return new CustomUser(user.getId(), user.getEmail(), user.getPassword().toLowerCase(), enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked,
        // getAuthorities(domainUser.getRole().getRole()));
                getAuthorities(2));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

/**
 * Retrieves a collection of {@link GrantedAuthority} based on a numerical role
 * 
 * @param role
 *            the numerical role
 * @return a collection of {@link GrantedAuthority

 */
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Integer role) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authList = getGrantedAuthorities(getRoles(role));
    return authList;
}

/**
 * Converts a numerical role to an equivalent list of roles
 * 
 * @param role
 *            the numerical role
 * @return list of roles as as a list of {@link String}
 */
public List<String> getRoles(Integer role) {
    List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (role.intValue() == 1) {
        roles.add("ROLE_USER");
        roles.add("ROLE_ADMIN");

    } else if (role.intValue() == 2) {
        roles.add("ROLE_USER");
    }

    return roles;
}

/**
 * Wraps {@link String} roles to {@link SimpleGrantedAuthority} objects
 * 
 * @param roles
 *            {@link String} of roles
 * @return list of granted authorities
 */
public static List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> roles) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    for (String role : roles) {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
    }
    return authorities;
}

public void logUserIn(User21 user) throws Exception{
    UserDetails userDetails = loadUser(user);
    Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
}
```

I based my dev on this great article

http://www.jiwhiz.com/post/2013/2/Add_RememberMe_Authentication_With_Spring_Security

but there must be something I miss.

Thanks!

Comment: Any error/exception trace?

Comment: There are no errors, the user is logged in but it does not save anything on my collection.

I think I am just missing the trigger or flag to point Spring Security it has to save the tokens.